# Gravity, entropy, and spacetime

Tags: general-relativity

Not to be redundant, but in reviewing the discussions about space time, the only conclusion I can come to is that there is no such thing as gravity.  It seems that because we cannot see the time dimension, what appears to us as gravity is only a symptom of space time distortion.  But the question remains, why does mass distort space Time?  Secondarily, as entropy continues to increase, is the endpoint a "flat" universe where we have evenly distributed energy only.  For the record, I am not a physicist.  I am just a lowly engineer asking simple questions.

Comment: This is a very good question. I don't have an exact answer, but I would like to say that entropy in space-time takes many forms, depending on the scale. Gravitational space-time in General Relativity is dominated metrically by light-years, so the choice of differential form for the stress-energy tensor is arbitrary to the magnitude of the vector between the celestial bodies. Although this arbitrariness does of course provide a constant residue that can either be open, flat, or closed alternatively. So this helps us make a choice to determine the most accurate differential form...